# Can you have two serializers for the same model that shows different things?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I want to differentiate what the user sees in my API when they want to see all the objects and when they want a specific object. Is it possible to do that and still relate to that particular model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that and still relate to that particular model?

Yes, It's possible to create as many as `serializer` for any object.

Let's say `User` is a model

So there can be two `serializer`

1 => `UserSerializer` # Which is default `serializer` for user object

2 => `CustomUserSerializer` #Which is another custom serializer for user object

> To use it

1 => `render json: user, status: 200` # This will calll default `UserSerializer`

2 => `render json: user, serializer: CustomUserSerializer, status: 200` # This will call `CustomUserSerializer`

Reference - [Custom ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#alias-attribute)